# some keyboard buttons don't work(calc and file shortcuts)

Tags: release-loki, keyboard

On my keyboard i have some userful key like one for go to homepage, one for launch music app and others, most of them works, other not.
I'm interested at "calc" and "file" key(i think the most userful), but they don't work.

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to add shortcuts for them.
In *System Settings* >*Keyboard* you'll find shortcuts for variety of functions and you can change keys to use these functions.

If you want to add a custom shortcut, go to the last tab where you can create your own shortcut - you define terminal command that is performed on event of clicking for example your calc key (maybe open calculator or libre office calc)

Comment: The problem is that i can assign all this keys because they are like the SHIFT button :(

Comment: It doesn't matter if you use these keys with shift or not. When mapping key to command you can click shift+your key and it saves event of clicking both keys at once.

Comment: The problem is that i can't map these keys, when assignign if i click only this keys commands say "disabled", but for example shift+Calc is accepted(another key+calc). So at the end, i can't use these buttons.

Comment: It seems that it's the same bug as it is with Print Screen. You can't assign this key separately, but with other key like shift.